# Loading a Library in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to load a library with the name Single_column. I create this library and I set it into the libraries folder. I have to mention at this point that I;m using the code Igniter framework. The Sinle_column class contain the following code:

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Single_column
{
    public function render( $id )
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        // DB calls
        // search for uri in db
        $CI->load->model('m_single_column');
        $image = $CI->m_single_column->getImageURI( $id );
        $text = $CI->m_single_column->getText( $id );

        // ==== HEADER
        // eventually, this will be loaded from the db
        $header_data['title'] = "Single Column Demo";
        $header_data['css'][] = "single_column";
        $CI->load->view('v_header', $header_data);

        // ==== CONTENT
        $content_data['content'] = '<div class="content-block">';
        $content_data['content'] .= '<div class="image">';
        $content_data['content'] .= '<img src="' . base_url() . $image . '" width="200" height="133" alt="my tractor"/>';
        $content_data['content'] .= '</div>';
        $content_data['content'] .= $text;
        $content_data['content'] .= '</div><!-- end content-block-->';

        $CI->load->view('v_content', $content_data);

        // ==== FOOTER
        $CI->load->view('v_footer');
    }
  }

 ?>
```

Now into the controller folder I have a class with the name:

```
 <?php

 if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Master extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();

     }

public function _remap($method) {
    // remap overrides function calls 
    // search for uri in db

    $this->load->model('m_master');

    $uri_id = $this->m_master->findURI(uri_string());
    $page;
    if ($uri_id != false) {       
        $this->{$page->controller}->render( $page->id );
    } else {
        show_404(uri_string());
    }
}

}

?>
```

The aforementioned code is from a tutorial and my problem is at the following line:

```
  $this->{$page->controller}->render( $page->id );
```

The displayed error is the following one:

```
   Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\application\controllers\master.php on line 24
```

Actually I realized that it can't recognize the method 'render'.
So, I tried the following lines of code into the if statement

```
  $library= Single_column::$uri_id['id'];;
  $this->load->library($library);
```

But I received the following error:
      Fatal error: Class 'Single_column' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\application\controllers\master.php on line 22

Moreover, the $uri_id returns an sql object. ButI want to pass only the id attribute of the object.

Question: How Can I call a library? And how can I pass a value into a method of a class(render method)? Why the aforementioned lines that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're loading a model into a library.

Make sure your library is also stored in `application/libraries`

```
$this->load->library('your_library_name');
$this->your_library_name->render($page->id);
```

This is similar to loading CodeIgniter libraries.

Comment: at the second line I receive the following error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\application\controllers\master.php on line 25